# How to find URL of local git repo

Tags: git

I'm about to start a new project and this time I will work with a peer. 
We want to use git (of course) to manage our code and we want to create a separate branch for each feature. We have also decided I will focus on the front-end while "the peer" will work on the back-end. Because of that "the peer" will never complete a feature by himself but once done I will take his code and complete the feature with the front-end. To achieve so I think the best way it is to add his repository as a remote of mine. My repo will have 2 remotes, 1 my "peer" local repo and 1 hosted online. I pull the feature branch for "the peer" repo and push the completed feature online.

Here my question: how can I know the URL of "the peer" local repo? 
How can I know what to put instead of question marks in the command below?

git remote add peer ????

My machine and "the peer"'s one are in the same network.

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: Are you using `gitosis` or some other `git` server mechanism? Are you intending on using `ssh` and granting your buddy filesystem permissions?

Comment: What OS are you (and your friend) using?

Comment: Why not using the same online repo together? Your peer will just be pushing to the separate 'back-end' branch and you will be using 'front-end' branch, then you may have a third branch for release (it might be a master branch in fact) where you will be merging yours and your peer's branches whenever needed and keep completed feature up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ssh access to the other repo:

```
git remote add peer username@host:/path/to/repository.git
```

Easier way: Setup a private repo on BitBucket and both of you start pushing to / pulling from that.

Comment: Thanks, BitBucket could be the solution

Answer (score 1):

Your peer can install an ssh server on his machine and let you to log in to access his repository. If you have this set up, then the remote address would be something like the following

```
username@peer-machine:/path/to/the/repository
```